# How to make a harware beep from a `/dev/pts` device?

Tags: terminal, audio, tty, echo

A harware beep can be generated from a non-GUI terminal with

```
echo -ne  '\007'
```

but nothing happens when this command is run from GUI terminal (say `gnome-terminal` from `/dev/pts/2`). Moreover

```
echo -ne  '\007' > /dev/tty2
```

from a GUI terminal does not produce any output.

**How to generate a hardware beep from a GUI terminal?**

Comment: It depends very much on the terminal, and how you've configured it - see the `visualBell` resource for XTerm, for example (presumably similar settings exist for other terminal emulators).  BTW, did you make a mistake in your first sentence?  Or do you have a different definition of GUI than the rest of us?